# Localization for Arabic language

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to translate all static element to my web page in Arabic by using angular.js, What all concept I can use. I have tried by using 


Its making my whole page to mirror image.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? It's not quite clear what your question is about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to implement localization on angular apps with ng-i18next. Check github repo at https://github.com/i18next/ng-i18next for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use angular-localization wich is the official way to do it https://github.com/doshprompt/angular-localization